# How to return an empty string in short OR operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

```
<FormItem
    hasFeedback
    validateStatus={ (isFirstRender) || (username && username.length > 6 ? "success": "error") }
>

</FormItem>
```

I am validating a user input. I want to validate the input only if it is not firstRender and i did `(isFirstRender) || (username && username.length > 6 ? "success": "error")` and this returns true if it is firstRender but validateStatus expects "","success","warning","error" and "validating". I want to return empty string if it is firstRender. How to accomplish that ?

Comment: Where does `isFirstRender` come from and what value would it have when the username should be checked?

Comment: Don't use `||` if you don't want to short-circuit on the falsy empty string. Make the condition explicit and use a conditional operator.

Comment: @down voter, please explain your reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain multiple ternary operators together, something like:

```
<FormItem
    hasFeedback
    validateStatus={(isFirstRender) ? "" : (username && username.length > 6 ? "success": "error") }
>

</FormItem>
```

As mentioned in the comments, this isn't really readable so I'd recommend pulling out the second ternary and storing it in a variable, as follows:

```
// somewhere above
const usernameStatus = (username && username.length > 6) ? "success" : "error";

// ...

<FormItem
    hasFeedback
    validateStatus={(isFirstRender) ? "" : usernameStatus }
>

</FormItem>
```

Comment: Thanks @Aquarthur. I can use terinary operator.

Comment: this is the clearest way as its just `if else` statements in html

Comment: Please don't ever use nested ternaries. They're unreadable and they make your coworkers hate your code.